# Replace String "\" to empty

Tags: c#, ios, string, xamarin

`"https:\/\/"`  Replace `"\"` to form http://

```
url = url.replace("\","");
```

Its not working in `Xamarin C# IOS.` 
Can any one advice me for replace `"\"` to `""`

Comment: Use "\\"? You need to escape the backslash with another backslash.

Comment: Does it even compile?  You can even see in the markup that that second quote is ignored.. double backslash.

Comment: `url = url.Replace(@"\", "");` or `url = url.Replace("\\", "");`

Comment: Can you show your actual code? That won't compile.

Comment: kiran, how do you get that string `https:\/\/`? Seems like it is data in a json string. Are you sure your input is not a json? If yes, then use a json parser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to capitalize the `replace()`. You also need to escape the "\" so it will be "\." Your code will work if you write `url = url.Replace("\\",string.Empty);`

Comment: I also used string.Empty. You can use either that or ""